# Why can I declare a ref struct as a member of a class in c#7.3?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, c#-7.3, ref-struct

According the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-struct-types):

> You **can't** declare a ref struct as a member of a class or a normal struct.

But I managed to compile and run this:

```
public ref struct RefStruct
{
    public int value;
}
public class MyClass
{
    public RefStruct Item => default;
}    
...       

MyClass c = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine(c.Item.value);
```

Now `RefStruct` is a `ref struct` and it is a member of a class.
Is this statement wrong in some cases?

**UPDATE**
Now the docs have been updated to a more precise description.

Comment: Try changing the value in `c.Item` and you'll see what you're *actually* doing with your declaration :)

Comment: Change the line to `public RefStruct Item { get; set; } = default;` Does that compile? What is the difference? What about `public RefStruct Item2()
            {
                return new RefStruct();
            }`? Is your code more similar to the former or the latter?

Comment: @mjwills no, it doesn't. I'm just complaining about the statement that `a ref struct can't be a member of a class`. But in fact, it can, semantically.

Comment: The docs are incorrect - or at least imprecisely worded. The compiler error is more accurate - `Field or auto-implemented property cannot be of type 'Program.RefStruct' unless it is an instance member of a ref struct.`. The key principle here is that the compiler is **enforcing that the object lives on the stack**. It won't allow anything that results in the object living on the heap (whether that is a field or a field-backed property). I'll leave feedback on the page for you.

Comment: @mjwills The error is confusing. Then how can I properly implement a `ref struct` non-auto property? Apparently, you can 't use a private field because that's not allowed. Then what can you do in the setter? only side effects?

Comment: What part of the error is confusing? It is saying you can't have a field (whether an explicit field, or an implicit field behind an auto property) that is a ref struct. If you want to do that, the answer is **you can't**. ;P `Then what can you do in the setter?` Whatever you want (e.g. `new` up the ref struct, write to the console etc etc). **As long as you don't have an explicit or implicit field that is a ref struct.** Any case you can think of is covered 100% by that error message. It is very precisely and accurately worded (unlike the docs).

Comment: @joe - you can store content of `ref struct` in setter and recreate it in getter (I've added it to my answer).

Comment: @SeM As I said - the docs are incorrect / imprecise. I pointed him to a better source of information, the error message itself. I have left them feedback to fix the docs. I have tried to explain the _principle_ that the compiler is enforcing. I am not sure what else I can say.

Comment: The docs have now been improved - https://github.com/dotnet/docs/commit/80f0635717a17b117edfcc8d0a3160c76c6d145b .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not field of your class but rather return value of a property getter - which is fine as it is just function return value.

Note that "as a member of a class" usually includes properties and probably should be changed to "field of a class".

If you would try to declare it as a class field (either directly or indirectly via auto-implemented property) this will require part of the class (the data for `ref struct`) to be allocated on the stack and the rest allocated in manged heap.

The code in the question defines non-autoimplemented property. As result there is no need for compiler to automatically create hidden field of the property type in the class. So while property result type is `ref struct` it actually is not stored in the class and hence does not violate requirement for this `ref struct` type not be included into any class. Note that even making setter method would be fine by itself - storing value for that property would be tricky, but you can safely store content of the `ref struct` (`public int value;` as in the post) in `set` and recreate it in `get`.

Comment: You can't create a property of `ref struct`, the compiler will give an error: _"Field or auto-implemented property cannot be of type 'RefStruct' unless it is an instance member of a ref struct."_

Comment: Yea, I get it, I think the doc needs some improvements. @SᴇM I think you need to set the getter instead of using the auto one.

Comment: @joe Sure if you create just a Property with getter returning default, it will be the same as you have declared. For example: `public RefStruct MyProperty { get { return default; } }` and it's equivalent to `RefStruct MyMethod() => default;`.

Comment: @SᴇM I think I've added explanation about your comment - see if that's enough.